# Forcing a goroutine to run X times a second

Tags: go, goroutine

Is there a way to force that a goroutine will run X times a second, no matter if there are other goroutines which may be doing a CPU intensive operation?

A little background on why, I am working on a game server written in go, I have a goroutine that handles the gameloop, the game is updated at X ticks per-second, of course some of the operations the server does are expensive (for example, terrain generation), currently I just spawn a goroutine and let that handle the generation in way that would not block the gameloop goroutine, but after testing on a server with a single vcore, I saw that it still blocks the gameloop while doing CPU intensive operations.

After searching online I found out that go would not reschedule a goroutine while it is not in a blocking syscall, now I could do as suggested which is to just manually call reschedule for the goroutine, but that has two problems, it will make the cpu intensive code more messy, with needing to handle timeouts at specific points, and even after manual reschedule it could just reschedule another cpu intensive goroutine instead of the gameloop...

Comment: This is no longer true: "...go would not reschedule a goroutine while it is not in a blocking syscall". What version of go are you using? Since v 1.14, goroutines are preemptible.

Comment: I am on 1.15.2, is it possible that it doesn't preempt fast enough for the gameloop to run at X ticks per second?

Comment: If you need to run a goroutine X times per second, use a ticker to receive a tick X times per second, measure, and if it cannot make the schedule then start looking for workarounds.

Comment: Yeah currently I am using a ticker, I think about just having a dedicated thread for the gameloop instead... was just hoping there is a better way to do it...

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to force that a goroutine will run X times a second, no matter if there are other goroutines which may be doing a CPU intensive operation?

No

> after testing on a server with a single vcore, I saw that it still blocks the gameloop while doing CPU intensive operations.

What else do you expect to happen? You have one core and two operations to be performed.

> After searching online I found out that go would not reschedule a goroutine while it is not in a blocking syscall

Not true.

From go runtime:

```
Goroutines are now asynchronously preemptible. As a result, loops without function calls no longer potentially deadlock the scheduler or significantly delay garbage collection. This is supported on all platforms except windows/arm, darwin/arm, js/wasm, and plan9/*.
```

Comment: I am wondering if there is a way to force the other goroutine to preempt while the game loop needs to run. The current behavior makes sense, it is just not the one I want... and yeah I was wrong on that reschedule, unfortunately most posts I seen are from couple of years ago...

Comment: @ItayAlmog What you are asking for is setting priority to goroutines. This concept has been discussed extensively and unfortunate for you but it is rejected. https://groups.google.com/g/golang-dev/c/HJcGESXfJfs